# SIMD (AVX2) mask store and pack

Tags: c, sse, simd, avx, avx2

I am trying to perform the following operation in AVX2 code (dest, data, and mask are int32 pointers):

```
int j=0;
for(i=0; i<N; ++i){
    if (mask[i]){
        dest[j++] = data[i];
    }
}
```

In AVX2, the closest instruction I can find is:

```
_mm256_maskstore_epi32(dest, (__m256*)mask, (__m256*)data);
```

But then I would need to perform the packing manually, which seems inefficient...

Comment: exact duplicate: producing a filtered copy of an array with AVX2.

Comment: My googling skill isn't quite there yet, but :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote my answer there.  I'm still pretty proud of the cool BMI2 trick using `pext`'s left-packing hardware to generate a shuffle mask. :)

Comment: done :). Thanks. I wish stackoverflow was more thanking friendly